# В MinGW отсутствуют возможности для полноценной работы с Socket'ами

Tags: c, сокет, mingw

Есть свои проекты, разработанные под Lin. Временно, возникла необходимость работать в Win. Соответственно, хотелось бы как использовать предыдущие наработки, так и корректировать и компилировать старые. Под Win использую для в качестве порта для gcc MinGW. Но, как оказалось, в MinGW нет возможности работать с *epoll* (нет инклюд *netinet/in.h*, *netinet/tcp.h* и т.п.). Собственно вопрос в том, есть ли какие-то решения?

P.S.: Виртуалку и буст - не предлагать.

Comment: А чем вам boost не угодил?

Comment: @VladD Мне кажется, что я уже Вам отвечал на этот вопрос ранее :) Пусть он перекочевывает потиху в стандарт C++ и я его буду использовать в виде STL без особых проблем. А качать стороннюю библиотеку для решения задач, которые очень легко решаются без нее, не вижу смысла. Что же касается текущего вопроса, то повторюсь еще раз: уже есть наработки. В тегах нет С++. Они без буста.

Comment: А, и правда, у вас чистый C. :) Извиняюсь за повтор вопроса.

Comment: @VladD Нет, конечно. Сами проекты на С++. Но вот что касается именно подключения и сокетов, то - да. А где там может быть С++?

Comment: Мне сложно сказать, я с сетью ни на C, ни на C++ не работал. Но мне казалось, что работу с сетью можно легко оформить в виде набора классов.

Comment: @VladD На С++ в STL ничего платформозависимого нет. И, в принципе, работа с сокетами на простом уровне такая и есть. Т.е. сами по себе простые функции они идентичны и в Win и в Lin. Но если писать что-либо более-менее серьезное, то уже вся кроссплатформенность летит к чертям. В свое время я дефайнами обрамлял некоторые вещи, чтобы работало и компилилось и в Win и в Lin. Но потом полностью перешел под Lin. И "забросил" кроссплатформенность.

Comment: @Abyx Это не пара тысяч и даже не тысяча строк кода. И все уже написано. И, пожалуйста, не вырывайте фразы из контекста.  Я писал в целом про буст, а Вы пытаетесь это сейчас "прицепить" к конкретному вопросу, в котором я уже описал другую причину, почему меня не устраивает буст.

Comment: @Abyx Если по простому, то ругается, что не может найти инклюды, такие как `#include <netinet/in.h>  #include <netinet/tcp.h>  #include <sys/epoll.h>`. Что предложите, кроме downvote?

Comment: @Abyx Так я и спрашиваю в вопросе, какие могут быть решения. Вас я услышал -  Ваше предложение переписать код под Win. Но оно мне не подходит.

Answer (score 3):

В WinAPI есть почти совместимая поддержка Berkeley Sockets.
Есть отличия в наборе поддерживаемых опций. Также, если используются асинхронные функции, то в Windows это сделано иначе. Ну и, как уже ответили, требуется добавить в код инициализацию и очистку (`WSACleanup`) и подключение динамических библиотек.

Дополнительная информация есть, например, в [Харт. Системное программирование в среде Windows](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/5-8459-0879-5.html).

**Резюме**
*(по итогам обсуждений в комментариях)*

Имеется проект, сделанный для операционной системы GNU/Linux. В проекте используется API GNU/Linux для работы с неблокируемыми сокетами (в частности, `epoll`). Проект реализован с использованием языка программирования C++.
Требуется перенести проект в операционную систему MS Windows с наименьшими трудозатратами. При этом желательно минимизировать внешние зависимости.

Предлагаемые варианты решения

1. Ограничиться использованием функции `select`, поддержка которой имеется в MS Windows. Требует изменения имеющегося кода, но отсутствуют внешние зависимости.
2. Использовать [кросс-платформенную библиотеку asio](http://think-async.com/). Также потребует изменения кода и добавляется внешняя зависимость. Взамен получаем кросс-платформенность на основе широко используемой библиотеки, которая, предположительно, войдет в стандартную библиотеку C++.

Также, для переносимости программ из GNU/Linux в Windows существует проект [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Однако, на первый взгляд, в нем нет поддержки `epoll`: [System interfaces compatible with GNU or Linux extensions](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-gnu.html) - возможно есть сторонние реализации. Использование Cygwin добавит внешние зависимости, также необходимо иметь в виду, что у этого проекта лицензия GPL.

Comment: Ну и как я уже ответил дважды в других комментариях: мне не достаточно простого примера с send и recv. На этом работа с сетью ограничивается только в институте при сдаче лабораторной. А чуть что сложнее и уже не то, что есть отличия, уже ничего похожего нет.

Comment: Ну мне не хватало. Хотя сейчас меня интересует не есть ли это в Win (и в Win и в Lin select есть), а могу ли я это использовать на порте gcc - MinGW.

Comment: Про буст я уже писал в самых первых комментариях... Что касается cygwin - я посмотрел, но это больше похоже на эмулятор или виртуальную машину. И тянется там, как я понимаю, чуть ли не все что можно и не нужно. Хотя, может я и ошибаюсь, близко не сталкивался.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде были там сокеты (когда-то пробовал).

Попробуйте компилировать

```
gcc ... -lws2_32 -lwsock32
```

и включать

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

Ну, и не забудьте

```
  WSADATA wsaData;
  WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
```

"магические заклинания" перед нормальной частью кода.

Comment: Ну, блин, я понимаю, что все в вопрос не вписал, но комментарии то можно было прочитать. Их не так же и много :) . То, что Вы написали - это, извините, для лабораторной работы в институте прокатит. Но для серьезного проекта используется гораздо больше (и других) функций, кроме socket, recv и send.

Comment: Вы про get/setsockopt? В моих тестиках вроде тоже есть. Вы бы лучше "огласили весь список".

Comment: Epoll. Думаю на этом список можно будет и закрыть. Если в Ваших тестиках встречается, то рад был бы помощи по портированию. Либо, для Win я могу переделать все под Completion Ports (хотя очень и очень не хотелось бы), если MinGW переварит его.

Comment: @MaxZS, это точно (там даже с select были проблемы). А помучившись месячишко с попытками реализовать  там нормально сигналы с EINTR и забил на эту дурь.

Comment: Я согласен "откатиться" с epoll на select. Для моего ближайшего проекта будет и select'a достаточно. Получиться ли это у меня на MinGW?

Comment: @MaxZS, не помню, что именно не получалось (но что-то работало не так). Судя по комментариям я возился с этим в 11-м году, так что, извините, придется Вам экспериментировать самому. Но, по крайней мере, код с select собирается.

Comment: Я люблю трудности преодолевать. Но тогда, когда знаю, что они преодолеваемы. В противном случае, я буду искать пусть трудный, но другой путь, с гарантированным успешным концом. Как вариант, подключение удаленной машины и компиляция на ней. Тот же NetBeans, вроде как позволяет это. Другой вариант, поставить рядом еще один комп (хотя он мне меньше улыбается). Да. Варианты - жесть. А я не из "Челябинска". Но какие надумал...

Comment: Кстати, попробовал настроить NetBeans на удаленную работу с VPS  и скомпилить проект - на удивление все легко получилось. Но это конечно же не то, что хотелось бы. Все-таки хотелось бы локальной работы.

Comment: @MaxZS, если Вам не нужны standalone .exe (как я понял из Вашего предыдущего комментария), то почему бы для \*nix программирования в винде в самом деле (как уже советовал Konstantin Les) не использовать cygwin (или [msys](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/MSYS/))?

Comment: Таки да.Мне не нужен exe под Win.Ну и еще до того,как задать вопрос,я посмотрел на cygwin.У меня сложилось впечатление,что это или эмулятор или виртуальная машина со всем добром полноценной оси.Хотя,может я и ошибаюсь.Но если это так,то тогда уже проще другой комп использовать.А msys...Так на его основе и работает MinGW.Без него MinGW ничего и не сделает. P.S:Пока я удаленно работаю,но уже столкнулся с некоторыми неудобствами,которые пока не так велики,чтобы ставить виртуальную машину.В целом же ожидалось,что может быть к MinGW можно докрутить недостающее звено.Или что есть аналогичные пакеты.

Comment: @MaxZS, как раз msys-1.0.dll в msys это и есть, то самое "недостающее звено", которое прикручено к MinGW для \*nix функциональности. А вообще-то, MinGW это компилятор, несколько binutils, \*.h и библиотеки (в основном с переходниками к WinAPI), и все это работает независимо от msys, которая  и использует MinGW. Между прочим, виртуалка (у меня VirtualBox с Ubuntu) хороший вариант (если железо позволяет).

Comment: Ну вот напишите выше Abyx, что MinGW - это компилятор с библиотеками и инклюдами (как это сказано,например, в той же википедии). А то он так не считает и приведет Вам ссылку на более опытных людей на х.з. каком ресурсе. Только сильно не ругайтесь с ним :)  А что касается MSYS, так я и говорю, что без него MinGW ну ничего не сделает (ну точнее, того, что мне нужно - Lin под WIn). Если мне нужно сугубо под Win работать, то запускается MSVS - лучшего пока ничего нет.

Comment: @Abyx, не знаю, как там у людей, а у меня MinGW на Win7 работает из C:\MinGW\bin без msys (конечно, это совершенно не Lin под Win)

Comment: @Abyx Прочитайте мои комментарий выше и поймете, что лично я ничего не выдумывал. Возможно, описался (или не так понял) avp.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант установить [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/). Там есть все нужные файлы включения для работы с сокетами. Компилятор MinGW-w64 в комплекте идет. Есть пакетный менеджер pacman.

[image: include1]

[image: include2]
Надеюсь, это вам поможет.

UPD: целевая платформа: Windows.